# Keystone Admin UI not always loading CSS

Tags: keystonejs

I don't see the CSS on admin page after installing the keystone.

on terminal I see following response.

```
GET / 304 385.936 ms
GET /keystone/signin 200 302.921 ms
GET /keystone/images/logo.png 302 7.281 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

first uninstall the keystone module

```
npm uninstall keystone
```

change your package.son file and take the keystone directly from GIT

```
"keystone": "https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone.git",
```

now install the keystone

```
nam install keystone
```